# Disable focus depending on previous blur

Tags: javascript, events, promise

Suppose I have 2 simple inputs like:

```
I1: <input id='I1' type='text' value=''>
I2: <input id='I2' type='text' value=''>
```

and the corresponding JS so I2 only can get focus if I1's value is OK:

```
var ok = true;
$('#I1').on('blur', function(e) { ok = doSomeErrorChecking(); } );
$('#I2').on('focus', function(e) { if( !ok ) e.target.blur(); } );
```

This works well as long as "doSomeErrorChecking()" returns true/false almost immediatelly.

My problem is when "doSomeErrorChecking()" has to call some Ajax stuff and does not returns true/false anymore, but a Promise.

How do I create this "onFocus" function at this conditions?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in many ways but an easy approach will be  to add a disabled attribute on `I2` input. And when `Ajax` resolves, you can remove this attribute from `I2`

Something like

```
I1: <input id='I1' type='text' value=''>
I2: <input id='I2' type='text' value='' disabled>
```

And your script would look something like

```
 $('#I1').on('blur', function(e) { 
     $.get("url", function(data, status){
    //work on data
     $("I2").prop("disabled", false)
    });
 } );
```

Comment: `$("I2").prop("disabled", false);` to keep things consistent :)

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks

Comment: Humm, that's fine, but let me rephrase my question. What If I had not 2, but, lets say, 30 inputs, all interdependent (I5 depends on I3 and I2, I10 on I2, I25 on I3, I2 and I10,  and so on), would you still use this kind of solution? Thanks!

Comment: OK. are sending `Ajax` request on blur for every field ?

Comment: Maybe. The thing is that i want to build something more generic, that could be used almost the same way if i have only 2 inputs or 30, and If "doSomeErrorChecking()" is resolved locally or with Ajax

Comment: And, yes, i have these situations on my forms, lots of Fields need to be validated by Ajax and others depending on them